# jquery and jquery-ui don't work with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have installed jquery via `npm install jquery` in my ui folder (folder where I also created react app via `npx create-react-app`). I also included those imports in my Container.jsx file:

```
import jQuery from "jquery";
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';
```

But whenever I try to run the app via npm start I get this:

```
./src/components/container/Container.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui' in 'C:\Users\nikol\Desktop\Project-D\ui\src\components\container'
```

[Failed to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gxUJ.png)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Why do you even need the third import? `import 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui';`